# NSManagedObjectContext concurrency

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency

In the documentation: [NSManagedObjectContext Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/) it states:

> Setter methods on queue-based managed object contexts are thread-safe. You can invoke these methods directly on any thread.

Can someone give a code example of what exactly this means. Does it actually mean to read "Setter methods on queue-based managed OBJECTS are thread-safe"

Also, if I have a managed object stored as an iVar (not best practice), can I called it's managedObjectContext method and its and then call performBlock() on this safely from within any thread?

Comment: I recommend you to have a look to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875917/core-data-concurrency-queue-style-moc-getters-thread-safety

Answer (score 3):

No, it means exactly what it says.  You can call setter methods on a `NSManagedObjectContext` from any thread. eg: `-[setParentContext:]`, `-[setPersistentStoreCoordinator:]`.

You can call `-[performBlock:]`and `-[performBlockAndWait:]` from any thread as it will execute the passed block on the context's queue.

Comment: To add to this correct answer, yes you can call `self.myManagedObject.managedObjectContext.performBlock...` if you wanted to.  That is also safe.  You cannot call anything that will potentially alter the state of the `NSManagedObject` instance on any thread but the thread that the context was assigned to.

Comment: Cool thanks. Got the info I needed from Marcus' other post.

Answer (score 0):

`-[performBlock:]` and `-[performBlockAndWait:]` are used to your app avoid accessing a managed object context or managed object from the wrong dispatch queue.

Let's imagine I have set up the managed object context as a background context with PrivateQueueConcurrencyType and we run this code on the main thread:

```
NSManagedObject *mo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Address" inManagedObjectContext:backgroundContext];
mo.street = "Rue la place"
[backgroundManagedObjectContext save:&error]
```

This piece of code violates Core Data’s concurrency model by calling `-[insertNewObjectForEntityForName::]` with the private queue context as an argument from the main thread.

So we should wrap all access to backgroundContext in a block passed to performBlock: or performBlockAndWait:, which executes the block on the context’s private dispatch queue:

```
[self.backgroundManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
  NSManagedObject *mo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Address" inManagedObjectContext:backgroundContext];
  mo.street = "Rue la place"
  [backgroundManagedObjectContext save:&error]
}];
```

Comment: Excellent answer but doesn't answer the question on whether setters on the context are thread-safe or if setters on the managed objects are thread safe.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should add that setters are thread-safe as long as it is called from the thread that the context was assigned. That's why performblock should be used.

Comment: Also, the setters on the *context* **are** thread safe.  Calling `-setParentContext:` and `-setPersistentStoreCoordinator:` is perfectly safe from any thread.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but as Marcus points out too, it's not quite what I was asking.